# When a react app is accessed are all components downloaded at once?

Tags: php, reactjs

I'm trying to wrap my head around React apps. As a PHP developer, I'm used to template blocks being downloaded depending on the route requested. It seems that in React apps all components are downloaded upon initial request and then simply wait to be called and passed its required data. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Comment: On modern web development, everything gets compiled into a single js file. It's like an apk file for android applications. It gets downloaded once and it's like you have an app installed in your browser (in cache)

Comment: Thank you. That's the perfect way to put it for this fellow.

Answer (score 1):

The determination of whether or not all components are downloaded as part of the "initial request" isn't actually something that React as a framework decides. This is completely up to you.

A React component in this situation is really represented by the JavaScript code used to render that component. If you are bundling all of your JavaScript code into a single file *app.js* and then adding a `<script>` reference to that file in your HTML then the answer is yes.

If your app is made up of many components and each page only shows a very small subset of this pool of components, then it could be beneficial for the performance of your app to use the strategy of [code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/), whereby a page only loads the JavaScript relevant to the inner workings of that specific page. Then, as a user navigates around the app, it pulls down more and more of the backing code so that it can correctly render / compute whatever the user is trying to see / do.